# How to query all values in vertices using elasticsearch in Tinkerpop3 graph

Tags: titan, gremlin, tinkerpop3

I have a graph that I want to to query vertices (full text search) by text that might occur in any of the keys in each vertex. How to do that?

I use Titan 0.9.0-M2 and Tinkerpop 3. The indexing backend is Elasticsearch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say your index is called `vertices`, then you would do:

```
graph.indexQuery("vertices","v.*:term").vertices()
```

Here's an example over the Graph of the Gods:

```
gremlin> graph.indexQuery("edges", "e.*:loves").edges()*.getElement()*.value("reason")
==>loves waves
==>loves fresh breezes
```

Comment: What does `e.*:loves` mean?

Comment: If any property value of the current edge matches "loves", the whole edge is a match.

Comment: That's exactly what I need. Thanks.